# Get form element value in onClick

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

How do I get the value of an element in a form in the `onClick` method?

Currently I have

```
<form id="addItemToCart" name="addItemToCart"><div align="right">Qty : <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" size="1"></div>
</td>
<td>
<a onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', this.addItemToCart.quantity.value);" class="button" id="button-cart"><?php echo $button_buy; ?></a></form>
```

Yet `this.addItemToCart.quantity.value` do not get any value and the function is not called. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the bad markup, you could use `document.getElementById('quantity').value`.

Comment: I'm supposed to add this in `addToCart` function, is that right?

Comment: You could do it there, or you could do it in place of `this.addItemToCart.quantity.value`.

Comment: `document.getElementById('quantity').value` actually works. Thank you so much. Will mark this as answer as soon as I can in 6 minutes :)